# FbxManager error Efailure and unexpected file type error

Tags: c++, import, fbx

I am having an issue where my FbxImporter fails to initialize. The ErrorString it returns when I call GetStatus.GetErrorString() is "Unexpected File Type". The Error code for the status is EFailure(after looking this up all autodesk says about is it means it failed). I have tried many different fbx files, and none of them seem to work. Also, I have included them in the visual studio project, and even with the executable(I know this is not the reason because other files load just fine). After looking around, there really is no forum post or anything that helps me with my problem.

Here is a snippet of my importer code.

```
//set up the fbxmanager
    FbxManager* fbxManager = FbxManager::Create();

    //set the settings for the manager
    FbxIOSettings* ioSettings = FbxIOSettings::Create(fbxManager, IOSROOT);
    fbxManager->SetIOSettings(ioSettings);


    //set the settings for the fbx io settings
    //create and init the importer
    FbxImporter *importer = FbxImporter::Create(fbxManager,"");

    //create and init the scene
    FbxScene* fbxScene = FbxScene::Create(fbxManager, "");

    //init the importer
    result = importer->Initialize(filename,-1, fbxManager->GetIOSettings());
    if (!result)
    {
        string error = importer->GetStatus().GetErrorString();
        FbxStatus status = importer->GetStatus().GetCode();
        return false;
    }
```

If I need to clarify the question or you need more information to answer my question please say so, thanks.

Comment: Are you using WinRT API? I got the same issue when I used it in an universal app project.

Comment: No I was not using a universal app project or the winRT api.Just the win api and dx 11_0

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out how to solve it!

There are two types of FBX file.

1. Binary FBX
2. ASCII FBX

Whenever you try to do

```
importer->Initialize(filename,-1, fbxManager->GetIOSettings());
```

with Binary FBX, it causes "Unexpected File Type".
However, if you convert binary FBX to ASCII FBX by [FBX Converter](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=22694909%22FBX%20Converter%22), your program will be able to read the file.

P.S: Sample program can read the binary FBX. I think FBX has a different version and it causes compatibility issues.